# GDBM doesn't work with Python 3.6 and anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, dbm, gdbm

I use Python 3.6 in an anaconda environment.
I installed GDBM with

```
conda install gdbm
```

The installation went well, however I can't use `dbm.gnu` from Python:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdbm'
```

It seams that Python doesn't include the `_gdbm` module, even if GDBM is actually installed.

Is this a known problem? How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

I faced this issue as well. This is probably not the ideal way, but it works.
I did the following to resolve this -

```
sudo apt-get install python3-gdbm
```

This installs the gdbm library for python3, however since apt-get and anaconda are two independent package managers; this isn't going to solve your problem. We primarily do this to get a hold of the .so shared library which we will place in the right folder in our anaconda installation. Next we find the location of the .so file using -

```
dpkg -L python3-gdbm
```

This gives us the following output -

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3.5
/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python3-gdbm
/usr/share/doc/python3-gdbm/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python3-gdbm/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3-gdbm/README.Debian
```

The file we require is here -

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Copy this file to the lib-dynload folder of your anaconda installation; for me this was -

```
cp /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload
```

Note, that this will only work if the directory the `.so` was copied to is in python's `sys.path`. To find the correct directory to copy to, assuming you're inside the activated conda environment, run:

```
python -c 'import sys; [print(x) for x in sys.path if "lib-dynload" in x]'
```

For example, in my case, the directory was inside the environment path and not in the anaconda main library. `~/anaconda3/envs/myenvname/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload`

Now try importing the module in python -

```
from _gdbm import *
```

or testing it from the command line:

```
python -m dbm.gnu
```

This should have fixed your problem.

Please note, mine is an Ubuntu-16.06 OS and my python version is 3.5.2.
The .so file may work with python3.6 as well, if not you can try installing python3.6-gdbm, although a quick search for ubuntu 16.04 didn't give me any results.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I did not success to make it works before your answer so I wrote [an alternative based on SQLite](https://github.com/Picani/SQLiteKV) which have very good perf in my use-cases. I'll edit this comment if I have time to test your solution.

Comment: I used the 3.5 version for conda 3.7 and it worked fine by renaming the file. Thanks. You might want to set permissions like the other files in the directory.

Comment: Thank you for this useful hack, @Savvy. I edited your answer to add a programmatic way to find the destination directory, since in my case it was under the environment lib path and not in the main anaconda lib path.

Comment: I had to copy the library to `~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/` but then it worked at once.  Thanks!

Comment: I did the same as colin, changing the file name from _gdbm.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so to _gdbm.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so and setting permissions to rwxrwxr-x using chmod 775 _gdbm.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is for Python3, I got here while trying to install `gdbm` on Python2 so I post my answer as it may be useful for others. The correct command was `conda install python-gdbm`. Although `conda install gdbm` went through, the module couldn't be imported. As per [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/74On3k-ovNM), however, this may not work for Python3.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @stason worked for me with a little modification regarding the destination route for the .so file. I copied the files to the lib-dynload folder in the environment to make this work.

Instead of: `/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.X/lib-dynload`

I used: `/home/username/anaconda3/envs/**your_env**/lib/python3.X/lib-dynload`

Doing the same but pointing to this folder worked for me. I hope this helps anyone with the issue.

Thanks!